# Determine first 50 likes via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get for example the first 50 people who liked a post, photo, whatever I created on facebook via the Graph API? Is there any kind of order when accessing connections like /likes or /comments?

Answer (score 0):

ASFAIK, you cannot get a list of people who like a page.  It's a privacy issue.  If you wanted to create an app, and users authorized your app, then you could get a list of the current users friends who like the page.

Comment: I just want the first 50 to like a page/post/whatever I created. Not their friends or something.

Comment: Facebook do not give you access to this info.  Think about it in terms of privacy.  It is not public information that you like a page called 'I Go Both Ways'.  Only your friends can see that.  Even the owner of a page cannot see which users like the page.

Comment: yes, for page this is true. i will remove that from the question. let's assume just posts, photos and other artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link (given that you have permissions to access to the post):

/likes?limit=50

This should be the first 50 likes ordered via Facebook (usually based on time).

Comment: That would work if you want to see what a user likes.  I think the question is asking which users like a page.

Comment: correct @Todd Chaffee. I can see who likes a post for example. But in which order do those likes occur? I want to identify the 50 people who liked this thing first.

Comment: The ordering is not defined as far as I can see.